# How to apply a lemma to 2 hypothesis

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

```
Theorem ev_plus_plus : forall n m p,
  even (n+m) -> even (n+p) -> even (m+p).
Proof.
  intros n m p Hnm Hnp.
```

We get this:

```
1 subgoal (ID 189)
  
  n, m, p : nat
  Hnm : even (n + m)
  Hnp : even (n + p)
  ============================
  even (m + p)
```

Also we have a previously proven theorem:

```
ev_sum
     : forall n m : nat, even n -> even m -> even (n + m)
```

We know that `(n+m)` is even and `(n+p)` is even.
How to create a new hypothesis in the context by applying ev_sum to Hnm and Hnp:

```
Hsum: even((n+m) + (n+p))
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options for this.
You can use `pose proof` like this:

```
pose proof (ev_sum _ _ Hnm Hnp) as Hsum.
```

it will do what you expect.
It allows you to give a term and add it as a hypothesis.

Another option is to use `eapply ... in`.
For instance you can do

```
eapply ev_sum in Hnm.
```

And then you have to give it `Hnp` in one of the subgoals.

Comment: eapply is worse, it creates 2-nd subgoal to prove.

Comment: Yes. But in some cases it can still be useful. :)

Comment: One can also do `assert (Hsum: even((n+m) + (n+p))) by (auto using ev_sum).`

Comment: Sure, but this loses all the advantages of `apply` where you don't have to give the type.